# how to install reactjs npm package correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm

Hi I want to install this reactjs package called react-dropdown-input
https://github.com/RacingTadpole/react-dropdown-input/

I ran this command

```
$npm install react-dropdown-input --save
```

in my local folder in git bash. After that I checked my package.json, it says  `"react-dropdown-input": "^0.1.11"` which means i have installed it correctly.

Then i tried to use it in my js file

```
    import React from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    var DocumentTitle = require('react-document-title');
    //var DropdownInput = require('react-dropdown-input');
```

When i added the fifth line, my page just could not load anymore (a blank page)
I dont know how to fix this.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

  const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BaseFolder = 'static/'; //relative to html path
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractLess = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
});

var loaders = ['babel-loader'];
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var vendor = ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'whatwg-fetch', 'es6-promise'];
var outputDir = 'dist';
var entry = {
     filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
}
var plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name:'vendor',
        minChunks: Infinity,
        filename: BaseFolder + 'js/[name].js',
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
}),
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    'BaseFolder': JSON.stringify(BaseFolder)
}),
//new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({maxChunks: 1}),
extractLess,
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'es6-promise',
    fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    React: 'react',
    jsSHA: 'jssha',
    wx: 'weixin-js-sdk'
}),
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
        from: 'src/images',
        to: BaseFolder + 'images'
    }
])
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    //devtool ='eval-source-map';
    loaders = ['react-hot-loader'].concat(loaders);
    plugins = plugins.concat([
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]);
    entry = Object.keys(entry).reduce(function (result, key) {
        result[key] = [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:' + port,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        entry[key]
    ];
    return result;
}, {});
}

 entry.vendor = vendor;

module.exports = env => {
return {
    entry: entry,
    output: {
        filename: BaseFolder+'js/bundle.js',

        chunkFilename: BaseFolder+'js/[id].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputDir),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    externals: [

    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: loaders,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: __dirname
            },
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: loaders, include: __dirname},
            { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap&includePaths[]=node_modules/compass-mixins/lib'},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader', exclude: /\.useable\.css$/},
            {
                test: /\.useable\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader/useable'
                    },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                ],
            },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&name='+BaseFolder+'images/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name='+BaseFolder+'fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&name='+BaseFolder+'fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name='+BaseFolder+'fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name='+BaseFolder+'images/[name].[ext]' },


        ]
    },

    plugins: plugins
}
};
```

Comment: Does the page have any error logged to the browser console?

Comment: Are you bundling it with Webpack and have the right loaders? Because "require" isn't valid JS in the browser, it needs to be transpiled to vanilla js :)

Comment: @dogui No. It just went blank after i refreshed the page. Im testing it on localhost:3000

Comment: What did you use to set up your React app? Was it `create-react-app` or a custom solution? In any case, try `import DropdownInput from 'react-dropdown-input'`.

Comment: @cbll Document Title package worked fine so i think its probably not because of that?

Comment: @dogui I just tried that. the same thing happened after i added that line

Comment: npm i react-dropdown-input should work so webpack link automaticly to this packages

Comment: @Alex It didnt work :((

Comment: this is old question , but you can use this repository : 
https://github.com/nimahkh/react-all-in-one-package
it helps me

Answer (score 1):

Yes this must be included in your node_modules, but the point is that you have include that in your compiled js file or not, i.e.

you must have used webpack or gulp to compile all your dependencies of js to give one file and you must have forget to include that dependency file in webpack file or gulpfile, Please check or provide sample of your webpack or gulpfile.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `DropdownInput` is named export from `react-dropdown-input` since in index.js file in the repository its exported as

```
module.exports = DropdownInput;
```

So need to import it like

```
import {DropdownInput} from 'react-dropdown-input'
```

Comment: Didnt work :( The page went blank after i refreshed it

Comment: Are you using webpack